# is it possible to get cross domain SOAP request using jquery

Tags: jquery

i am using a javascript to get a soap response 
but after a lot of pain i realized that it is not possible to get cross domain xml http request.
so i decided to move on to jquery
now i dont need a code to that
i just need some tips and confirmation if possible in jquery
below is code for my js
 var getmarket = new XMLHttpRequest();
        getmarket.open('POST', 'http://www.betfair.com/publicapi/', true);

```
    var m_request = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" '+
                    'xmlns:bfex="http://www.betfair.com/publicapi/v5/BFExchangeService/" '+
                    'xmlns:v5="http://www.betfair.com/publicapi/types/exchange/v5/">'+
                    ' <soapenv:Header/>'+
                    '<soapenv:Body>'+
                    '<bfex:getAllMarkets>'+
                    '<bfex:request>'+
                    '<header>'+
                       '<clientStamp>0</clientStamp>'+
                       '<sessionToken>Y9eTuEvlrTM55pbRB1kIj0As0bVvz3eFm+p1FY+svHk=</sessionToken>'+
                    '</header>'+
                    '<locale>en</locale>'+
                    '<eventTypeIds>'+
                       '<v5:int>1</v5:int>'+
                    '</eventTypeIds>'+
                    '<countries>'+
                       '<v5:Country>GBR</v5:Country>'+
                    '</countries>'+
                    '<fromDate>2012-08-23TO00:00:00.000Z</fromDate>'+
                    '<toDate>2012-08-24TO00:00:00.000Z</toDate>'+
                 '</bfex:request>'+
              '</bfex:getAllMarkets>'+
           '</soapenv:Body>'+
        '</soapenv:Envelope>';

    getmarket.onreadystatechange = function (){
        if (getmarket.readyState == 4 && getmarket.status == 200)
        document.write(getmarket.responseText);
        }

    getmarket.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    getmarket.send(m_request);
    document.write(getmarket.responseText);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery is a wrapper around Javascript. If javascript won't do it JQuery wont either. You will have to get your server to do the lookup.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this, only [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) is allowed cross-domain.

also check this : [Cross-domain SOAP from the browser](http://www.jasonkolb.com/weblog/2006/05/crossdomain_soa.html)

Comment: Nice URL, especially the second one (the entire website). Thank you, would have never found my way there otherwise!