# how do i send a cross domain SOAP request using java script or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, soap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is it possible to get cross domain SOAP request using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090036/is-it-possible-to-get-cross-domain-soap-request-using-jquery)

please help me on a way to get a SOAP response from a different domain and parse it to display info on my web page.
i dont have access to the other DOMAIN.
i want to do this using javascript or jquery.
if not possible, what is the way to do it?

Comment: Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124269/simplest-soap-example-using-javascript

Comment: Do not post the same exact question twice! You waste people's time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the other domain is exposing its API via JSONP or HTML5 CORS, it is not possible short of setting up your own server as a proxy and then calling your server (bearing in mind others could theoretically access your proxy as well unless it is access protected).