# How make SOAP Request Cross-domain with JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, soap

I am using SOAP web-service to get the response from another server. I am using Jquery ajax call to get the data from server. But I am getting the **0**(zero) status code from server.

How do I achieve cross domain ajax calls using Jquery?

Comment: Before asking the question, show your code and the effort you have done on this problem. 

you cannot do a cross domain request until the server allows it. CORS support is basically checked by the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` Headers in the HTTP.  http://enable-cors.org/. if the servr supports CORS, then provide a callback.

Comment: there is a jquery plugin which uses the YQL API to do cross domain requests: https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax/

Comment: possible duplicate of [is it possible to get cross domain SOAP request using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090036/is-it-possible-to-get-cross-domain-soap-request-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to get cross-domain data with jQuery, try fetching the data with PHP or other language that allows cross domain access.  Create a PHP page that loads the SOAP data, and use jQuery to embed that information in your page.  Though it is not a SOAP connection, to illustrate the idea, you could create this PHP page to load a Youtube video:

```
<?php
$vid = filter_var($_POST['id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
?>
<?php if ($vid) : ?>
    <iframe title="YouTube video player" width="510" height="317" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $vid; ?>?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Then use jQuery to display it -- clicking a link could call this function:

```
function loadContent() {
$(this).parent().load("/youtube-video.php",{id:video_id},showNewContent());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be very vague. but below is one of the way to do a cross Domain Request in jQuery:

```
$(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                dataType:'jsonp',
                jsonp:'jsonp',
                url:'http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/tags/',
                success:function(data) {
                    $.each(data["tags"], function(index, item) {
                        var $tag = item.name;
                        var $count = item.count;
                        $("body").append('<div class="stackoverflow"> The Tag
              <span class="q-tag">' + $tag + '</span> has <
span class="q-count">'
 + $count + '</span> Questions.</div>')
                    });
                },
                error:function() {
                    alert("Sorry, I can't get the feed");  
                }
            });
        });
```

[**DEMO**](http://www.codeforbrowser.com/demos/stackoverflowtags.html)

[**DESCRIPTION OF THE ABOVE**](http://codeforbrowser.com/blog/cross-domain-request-with-jquery-and-jsonp/)